# Generate HTML form based on XML

Tags: java, html, xml, jakarta-ee

Is there any way apart of XSTL which dynamically generates HTML form based on metadata specified inside a XML? Take note that I'm developing a JAVA web application here. There won't be a lot of metadata inside the XML, which means that the XML is very simple. For worst case scenario, I would just build my own XML processor and generate HTML code with Java.

Comment: XSLT is perfect for this kind of thing so not quite sure of your reasons not to use it. One thought, is could you use a javascript templating engine using the XML file as a data source so that everything is rendered by the browser. Just a thought. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792634/jquery-xml-based-template-engine and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend

Comment: There are some limitations in XSLT which cause me not to use it.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483307/generate-html-form-dynamically-using-xml-and-reusable-xslt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXB) to map your XML to Java objects. Once you have the data in Java, you can plug it into the templating engine of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

One - less recommended - way is to display and style xml by use of css. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_display.asp) for an example.

I would tend to go for XSLT if you need to go from one XML format to another one (HTML in this situation) in 99% of the cases. Not sure why you have that scratched as an option already ..

Cheers,
Wim

Answer (score 0):

Its answered here : [Generate HTML form dynamically using xml and reusable xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483307/generate-html-form-dynamically-using-xml-and-reusable-xslt).

And complete example is described here : http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/09/xslt-using-reusable-xsl-to-generate.html

You have to extend xsl file (answered there) for complex html forms