# Generate HTML form dynamically using xml and reusable xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have large number of xml files :

First:

```
<xmldata1>
    <record>
        <property11>abc</property11>
        <property12>def</property12>
        <property13>xyz</property13>
        ............
    </record>
    ........
</xmldata1>
```

Second:

```
<xmldata2>
    <record>
        <property21>abc</property21>
        <property22>def</property22>
        <property23>xyz</property23>
        ............
    </record>
    ........
</xmldata2>
```

and so on.

There won't be any more nested tags .
But the name of property tag will be different for each xmldata file.

So i want to dynamically generate a `HTML` Form  using `XSLT` to be used to read data for each `xml` . Where a simple text box should be used to read each property. and we can take the first record as reference for number and name of properties.

The desired output

```
<form name ="xmldata1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>property11 :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="property11"></td>
        </tr>
        .......
        and so on
    </table>
</form>
```

How can i achieve this. Where can i find sample example for this.

Comment: Would be good to provide an example of what you've attempted and not expecting the community to write this for you, that is not the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <!--Template match for the document element, no matter what the name -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <form name="{local-name()}">
        <table>
           <!--Apply-templates for all of the record/property elements -->
           <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
         </table>
      </form>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Match on all of the property elements and create a new row for each -->
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="{local-name()}"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean sth like that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'xmldata')]">
    <xsl:element name="form">
        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></xsl:attribute>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'property')]">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:element name="input">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```